# How to use drag and drop in wpf for entire window with tab control and custom user controls?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I've created a text editor for a project and am attempting to allow users to drag and drop text files into the main window. In the main window there is a menu, a toolbar tray, and a tab control. In the tab control I generate tabs by allowing the user to open a file with open file dialog(adds a tab item and files it with text from the text file), and create a new file (Just adds a tab item). In the tab Items there is a custom widget that I add before adding them to the tab control . On the main window I add the following

```
AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="checkDraggedObject" Drop="getDroppedTextFile"
```

What I want this to do is allow the user to drag a file into the main window and create a new tab with the files contents. It works fine until I hover over the user control that has been added to the content of the tab item. When I try to add the properties to the user control it doesn't allow me to drop files while hoovering over the user control. When I hoover over the tool bar tray and or the menu it allows me to drop the files but it opens the file twice. How can I make it so that hoovering over the window no matter where allows the user to drop the file in?

Comment: Try setting `AllowDrop="True"` on the other UI elements too.

Comment: @Sheridan I tried that but all it did was add two tabs to the tab control. Each tab was filled with files content.